# compare NumPy vs. NumPy+MKL performance

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-12.04, scientific-computing, intel-mkl

So, I compiled NumPy from source, linking to MKL. Now I want to compare NumPy's performance with and without MKL. Is there any way I can "tell" NumPy not to use MKL, so I can produce the benchmarks? For instance, with numExpr we can do `numexpr.use_vml = False`. Is there anything similar for NumPy? I really don't wanna have to compile NumPy without MKL just for this.

(Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3, NumPy 1.8, Intel Composer XE 2013 SP1)

Comment: What did you end up with?

Comment: I wish I remembered (that was four years ago; sorry).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way is to compile NumPy again without MKL, preferably in a virtualenv....